# Question about the curvature of dual connection in a manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, information-theory, curvature, information-geometry

Let $S$ be a manifold on which there is given a Riemannian metric $g=<,>$ and two affine connections $\nabla$ and $\nabla^*$. If for all vector field $X,Y,Z$ of $S$
$$Z<X,Y>=<\nabla_{Z}X,Y>+<X,\nabla_{Z}^{*}Y>$$ holds then we say that $\nabla$ and $\nabla^*$ are duals of each other with respect to $g$.

Let the curvature tensor of $\nabla$ and $\nabla^*$ be denoted by $R$ and $R^*$ respectively,then we have $R=0\iff R*=0$ on the other hand it is not true for the torsion tensor $T$ and $T^*$.

Can someone explain this that how to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
\langle \nabla_i\nabla_j\partial_k,\partial_l\rangle
&=\partial_i\langle\nabla_j\partial_k,\partial_l\rangle-\langle\nabla_j\partial_k,\nabla_i^*\partial_l\rangle
\\
&=\partial_i\partial_j\langle\partial_k,\partial_l\rangle-\partial_i\langle\partial_k,\nabla_j^*\partial_l\rangle
\\&\quad-\partial_j\langle\partial_k,\nabla_i^*\partial_l\rangle+\langle\partial_k,\nabla_j^*\nabla_i^*\partial_l\rangle
\end{align*}
Subtracting this from the same equation with $i,j$ swapped we get
$$
R_{ijkl}=-R_{ijkl}^*.
$$